# Calling an async method inside Background worker dosen't report progress paralelly

Tags: c#, async-await, backgroundworker

I am calling an async method that returns a Task < CurrentCartridgeStatus> from Background worker. Thing is until the CurrentCartridgeStatus changes its state I want to keep calling it. But I am not awaiting on this method call because making the DoWork method async is giving me an exception.

But in my case with my current call(Please see the StartCurrentRun method) the background worker initially reports 1% then it seems to be staying idle, and after the status changes then it reports the rest 99%. Please help how can I make the Background worker report progress in parallel with StartCurrentRun method.

```
private void StartCurrentRun(bool obj)
        {
            this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this.worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            this.worker.DoWork += this.DoWork;
            this.worker.ProgressChanged += this.ProgressChanged;
            this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            IsLiveProgress = true;
            StartTimer();
            this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateEventLogs.WriteToEventLog(string.Format("Run with Assay:{0} Volume{1} has been started", SelectedAssay, SelectedVolume));
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            int current = 1;
            CurrentCartridgeStatus status = CurrentCartridgeStatus.NotProcessed;
            var instance = ConnectToInstrument.InstrumentConnectionInstance;
            do
            {
                var result = instance.StartCurrentRun(SelectedAssay.display_name, int.Parse(SelectedVolume.Remove(SelectedVolume.Length - 2, 2)));
                //var result = Test(current);
                status = result.Result;
                CurrentStatus = status.ToString();
                CreateEventLogs.WriteToEventLog("Run status - " + CurrentStatus);
                //Thread.Sleep(2000);
                worker.ReportProgress(Math.Min(current, 100));
                current++;
            }
            while (status != CurrentCartridgeStatus.Processed);
            ConnectToInstrument.IsAlreadyExecuted = false;
            if (current < 100)
            {
                worker.ReportProgress(current + (100 - current));
            }
        }
```

Here is the StartCurrentRun method. It internally calls some firmware logic. Just to make this more clear here is the entire ConnectToInstrument Class.

```
 public class ConnectToInstrument
    {

        private EventProxy _updater;
        private IInstrument _instrument;
        private QpCallBack _cb;
        //private IQEvent @event;
        private QpWrapper _qp;
        private InstrumentTypes _type;
        private CurrentInstrumentStatus InstrumentCurrentStatus = CurrentInstrumentStatus.NotReady;
        private static ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public static bool IsAlreadyExecuted = false;
        public bool IsConnected { get; set; }

        private static ConnectToInstrument _instrumentConnectionInstance;
        public static ConnectToInstrument InstrumentConnectionInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instrumentConnectionInstance == null)
                {
                    _instrumentConnectionInstance = new ConnectToInstrument();
                }
                return _instrumentConnectionInstance;
            }
        }

        private ConnectToInstrument()
        {
            try
            {
                _cb = new QpCallBack();
                _qp = new QpWrapper();
                //var config = new ConfigManager();
                //var client = new Dna2Client();
                _type = InstrumentTypes.Simulator;
                var factory = new ApiFactory(_cb, _qp, _type);
                _instrument = factory.GetInstrument();
                InitializeQf();
                _updater = new EventProxy();
                _updater.Start(1);
                StartUiProxy().Forget();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log to Error Log
            }
        }

        private async Task<object> StartUiProxy()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var @event = await _updater.GetEvent();

                    switch ((QpSignals)@event.QSignal)
                    {
                        case QpSignals.INSTRUMENT_STATUS:
                            {
                                var status = @event as UiEvent<InstrumentStatus>;
                                if (status.Value != InstrumentStatus.Ready)
                                {
                                    InstrumentCurrentStatus = CurrentInstrumentStatus.NotConnected;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    InstrumentCurrentStatus = CurrentInstrumentStatus.Ready;
                                    return Task.FromResult<object>(InstrumentStatus.Ready);
                                }
                            }
                        case QpSignals.TRAY_STATUS:
                            {
                                var status = @event as UiEvent<TrayStatus>;
                                if (status.QSignal == 6 && status.Value == TrayStatus.Opened)
                                {
                                    return Task.FromResult<object>(TraySignals.OPEN);
                                }
                                else if (status.QSignal == 6 && status.Value == TrayStatus.Opened)
                                {
                                    return Task.FromResult<object>(TraySignals.CLOSE);
                                }
                                return null;
                            }
                        case QpSignals.PROCESS_CARTRIDGE:
                            {
                                var status = @event as UiEvent<CartridgeStatus>;
                                if (status.Value == CartridgeStatus.Processing)
                                {
                                    return status;
                                }
                                else if (status.Value == CartridgeStatus.Processed)
                                {
                                    return status;
                                }
                                return null;
                            }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log to Error Log
                }
            }
        }

        private void InitializeQf()
        {
            QF.Instance.Initialize((int)QpSignals.MAX_SIGNAL - 1);
        }
        public async Task<bool> Connect()
        {
            bool status = false;
            string[] ports = new string[40];
            if (_type == InstrumentTypes.Dgx)
            {
                ports = await ComPortInfo.GetAvailablePortNamesForDevice("USB Serial Port");
                if (ports == null || ports.Length == 0)
                {
                    Exception ex = new Exception("No Serial Devices found.");
                    //Log
                    return false;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                string thermPort = _type == InstrumentTypes.Simulator ? string.Empty : ports[0]; //ports[0] should be changed to combobox selected value
                status = _instrument.Connect(ports[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Write(ex.Message);
            }

            return status;

        }

        public async Task<CurrentInstrumentStatus> GetCurrentInstrumentStatus()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(InstrumentCurrentStatus);
            //_cb.InstrumentStatusUpdates(InstrumentStatus.Ready);
            //var value = await _updater.GetEvent();
            //var status = value as UiEvent<InstrumentStatus>;
            //if (status.QSignal == 5 && status.Value == InstrumentStatus.Ready)
            //{
            //  return CurrentInstrumentStatus.Ready;
            //}
            //return CurrentInstrumentStatus.Error;
        }

        public async Task<CurrentCartridgeStatus> StartCurrentRun(string Assay, int volume)
        {
            object value;
            UiEvent<CartridgeStatus> status;
            do
            {
                //await Task.Delay(1000);
                //_cb.ProcessCartridge(CartridgeStatus.Processing);
                if (!IsAlreadyExecuted)
                {
                    _instrument.ProcessCartridge();
                }
                IsAlreadyExecuted = true;
                //value = await StartUiProxy();
                value = await _updater.GetEvent();
                status = value as UiEvent<CartridgeStatus>;
            }
            while (status == null);
            try
            {
                //IQEvent value;

                if (status.QSignal == 9 && status.Value == CartridgeStatus.Processing)
                {
                    return CurrentCartridgeStatus.Processing;
                }
                if (status.QSignal == 9 && status.Value == CartridgeStatus.Processed)
                {
                    return CurrentCartridgeStatus.Processed;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log it
            }

            return CurrentCartridgeStatus.Unidentified;
        }
    }
```

Here is the CurrentCartridgeStatus enum

```
  public enum CurrentCartridgeStatus 
    {
        Unidentified = 0,
        NotProcessed = 1,
        Processing = 2,
        Processed = 3
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `status = result.Result;` so it doesn't matter that `StartCurrentRun` is run async - you're blocking your calling code anyway. There must be a different problem with your code.

Comment: In any case, your code has a lot of variables that either are class-level variables (like `IsAlreadyExecuted`) or you've not posted your real code. It's really hard for us to reason with this code. You should really post a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue and is code that we can actually run. Then it is much easier to help you.

Comment: So If I remove the BackGround worker and create an async method that can await the StartCurrentRun and update progress will that solve my issue? Then the call will be parallel right?

Comment: No, `async` doesn't mean that things run in parallel - it just then won't block the UI thread.

Comment: The other issue seems to be that you're incrementing `current` and then reporting it via `worker.ReportProgress(Math.Min(current, 100));`, but there doesn't seem to be anything in your code that says you are processing `100` items. The `do`/`while` loop ends when `status != CurrentCartridgeStatus.Processed`. You need to rethink your entire method I think.

Comment: Your code is bad. Why do you have a `try`/`catch` block around the `//IQEvent value;` code? Nothing there looks like it can possibly through an exception.

Comment: what is `worker.ReportProgress(current + (100 - current));` supposed to do? looks like on the first run, say 1, it will call the method with 100. This is why you are seeing a jump from 1-99, because you call it initially with 1 from this line `worker.ReportProgress(Math.Min(current, 100));`

Comment: Hmm ok. I am incrementing like that because I cannot really divide the StartCurrentRun method into bits and pieces. If I really want to go that complicated I want to put in a Timer and then keep updating the Progress there. But I reposted my entire code. Any suggestions?

Comment: OfCourse the code is not refactored. I will have clear any non used logic.

Comment: The bottom-line is that you can't provide a progress bar that counts from 0 to 100 unless you know the count of items you're processing at the beginning. If you don't know the count then you can only show a continuously moving progress bar.

Comment: Hmm ok I wanted to try something like a small updating the progress mimic that something is happening. Thats why after I get a change in the Cartridge status I am updating the progress to 100 percent if there was any left over.

Comment: What if there are 200 cartridges to process? Your code would make it appear that it was complete after 100 were processed.